# Orchard CMS and the Path property in Module.txt

Tags: routes, orchardcms

In my module.txt I have this:

```
Name: My Module Name
Path: friendlyname
AntiForgery: enabled
Author: MyCompany
Category: MyCategory
Website: http://www.mycompany.com
Version: 1.0
OrchardVersion: 1.0
Description: Some description
FeatureDescription: Some description
Dependencies: Orchard.Users
```

When I want to access a method of a controller in my module I would expect to be able to use an url like this:

```
OrchardLocal/friendlyname/controller/action
```

However this does not work. It works only if I use the url like this:

```
OrchardLocal/assemblyname/controller/action
```

How can I use a friendly url that does not display the assembly name. My assembly name contains dots and the company name, so not so nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well apparently I asked the question too soon. Maybe some caching occured, because the way I described works now.

Comment: You sir just made my week. I've been struggling with these modules for the better part of this week. Many thanks